# Find Multiple Strings - Exact Match

Tags: string, excel, matching, vba

Having little trouble here in which I'm looping through a big document and highlighting strings.  Where I'm having trouble is two fold, eg.

Search Criteria "aaa" in cell "Baaa", this would get highlighted as a hit, which on some level makes sense, but I was hoping only to return highlight if exact match in string and length.  Also I'm curious if there is an easy way to compress the following:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim MyAr(1 To 1092) As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

MyAr(1) = "R833"
MyAr(2) = "R853"
MyAr(3) = "R873"

With ws
'~~> Loop through the array
For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
Set aCell = .Columns(23).Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
Set bCell = aCell
aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

Do
Set aCell = .Columns(23).FindNext(After:=aCell)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
Exit Do
End If
Loop
End If
Next
End With

With ws
'~~> Loop through the array
For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
Set aCell = .Columns(24).Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
Set bCell = aCell
aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

Do
Set aCell = .Columns(24).FindNext(After:=aCell)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
Exit Do
End If
Loop
End If
Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this `LookAt:=xlPart` in your `FIND` statement.
Change this to `LookAt:=xlWhole` to only search for exact matches.

Note: This means the whole cell must match, not just that one word amongst many in the cell.

To find an exact match on a word amongst many use `xlPart` but add a space at the start and end of your search term - search for " aaa " rather than "aaa".

**Edit:** It looks like your code could be shortened, unfortunately I haven't got the time to look at it at the moment.

Comment: This worked perfectly, such a small overlook causing a huge pain.  Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Darren Bartrup-Cook's comments, you can shorten it thus, though I doubt you need to search the full column?

```
Sub Sample()

Dim MyAr(1 To 1092) As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

MyAr(1) = "R833"
MyAr(2) = "R853"
MyAr(3) = "R873"

With ws
    '~~> Loop through the array
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        Set aCell = .Range("W:X").Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                       LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            Do
                aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Set aCell = .Range("W:X").FindNext(After:=aCell)
            Loop While aCell.Address <> bCell.Address
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```